# Convert data frame to JSON in this format

Tags: json, r, rjsonio, rjson

I have a data frame that I'm looking to output to JSON in a particular format, with a small sample below:

[image: raw data]

```
dat <- structure(list(unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
  date = structure(c(1357963687, 1357963869, 1357964048, 1357964230, 
  1357963687, 1357963942, 1357963942, 1357964123), class = c("POSIXct", 
  "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), latitude = c(-21.21, -21.22, -21.23, 
  -21.24, -21.23, -21.23, -21.23, -21.23), longitude = c(116.78, 
  116.77, 116.76, 116.75, 116.74, 116.75, 116.75, 116.76)), .Names = c("unit", 
  "type", "date", "latitude", "longitude"), row.names = c(NA, -8L
  ), class = "data.frame")
```

The JSON format that I'm going to need looks like this:

```
    [{"unit":"A","type":"X","latitude":[["2013-01-12 12:08:07",-21.21],["2013-01-12 12:11:09",-21.22],["2013-01-12 12:14:08",-21.23],["2013-01-12 12:17:10",-21.24]],
                           "longitude":[["2013-01-12 12:08:07",116.78],["2013-01-12 12:11:09",116.77],["2013-01-12 12:14:08",116.76],["2013-01-12 12:17:10",116.75]]
    },
    {"unit":"B","type":"X", "latitude":[["2013-01-12 12:08:07",-21.23],["2013-01-12 12:12:22",-21.23],["2013-01-12 12:12:22",-21.23],["2013-01-12 12:15:23",-21.23]],
                           "longitude":[["2013-01-12 12:08:07",116.74],["2013-01-12 12:12:22",116.75],["2013-01-12 12:12:22",116.75],["2013-01-12 12:15:23",116.76]]
    }]
```

I've been so far unable to manipulate the `RJSONIO::toJSON` function to do anything like that, and I'm not finding the examples in the documentation too helpful.

What do I need to do to get the right output?

Note: There will only ever be a single `type` for each `unit`.

PS: Is there a tool out there to make these kinds of things easy? Perhaps something drag and drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get close by first turning the data frame into a list of lists. For example:

```
> a=list(unit="A",type="X",latitude=c(1,2,3),longitude=c(4,5,6))
> b=list(unit="B",type="Y",latitude=c(11,22,33),longitude=c(43,54,65))
> dlist = list(a,b)
> cat(toJSON(dlist))
[
 {
 "unit": "A",
"type": "X",
"latitude": [      1,      2,      3 ],
"longitude": [      4,      5,      6 ] 
},
{
 "unit": "B",
"type": "Y",
"latitude": [     11,     22,     33 ],
"longitude": [     43,     54,     65 ] 
} 
]
```

The problem is really how to manipulate a dataframe into the right format.

However your JSON output has mixed types -character and numeric - in vectors: `["2013-01-12 12:08:07",-21.23]` and I don't see how to get that out of R which insists on vectors being a single type. Would `["2013-01-12 12:08:07","-21.23"]` be acceptable? If so then read on...

The `plyr` package has lots of code for splitting and manipulating data frames and lists. For example:

```
dlply(dat,~unit)
```

will split the dataframe by the `unit` variable. You can apply a function to each of these sections and return a list. This function:

```
make1 <- function(d){   
   list(
         unit=d$unit[1],
         type=d$type[1],
         latitude=cbind(as.character(d$date),d$latitude),
         longitude=cbind(as.character(d$date),d$longitude))
   }
```

Should convert one section into the right list format. So tell `dlply` to do that to every section, and return a list of lists. That list has names, which makes `toJSON` output as a named array - we need to remove the names to get a JS list.

```
> L = dlply(dat,~unit,make1)
> names(L)=NULL
> cat(toJSON(L))
 [
 {
 "unit": "A",
"type": "X",
"latitude": [ [ "2013-01-12 04:08:07", "-21.21" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:11:09", "-21.22" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:14:08", "-21.23" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:17:10", "-21.24" ] ],
"longitude": [ [ "2013-01-12 04:08:07", "116.78" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:11:09", "116.77" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:14:08", "116.76" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:17:10", "116.75" ] ] 
},
{
 "unit": "B",
"type": "Y",
"latitude": [ [ "2013-01-12 04:08:07", "-21.23" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:12:22", "-21.23" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:12:22", "-21.23" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:15:23", "-21.23" ] ],
"longitude": [ [ "2013-01-12 04:08:07", "116.74" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:12:22", "116.75" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:12:22", "116.75" ],
[ "2013-01-12 04:15:23", "116.76" ] ] 
} 
]
```

Fun eh?

Comment: That would be fine. I'll be able to type convert it in JS.

Comment: That's very helpful. Since `latitude` and `longitude` are actually arrays of arrays, I think I need to do this: `a=list(unit="A",type="X",latitude=list(c(1,10),c(2,12),c(3,13)),longitude=list(c(4,12),c(5,11),c(6,12)))`. Now just need to figure out how to apply this for arbitrary number of units (my full data set has hundreds of them, which wasn't clear in the initial question)

Comment: Re: Your complete answer. Well done. Great explanation and compact code. Thank you kindly!